# Partial input to interactive command

Tags: interactive

Let's say I want to provide partial input to an interactive function such as `insert-char`. For example, I might want to have a command that automatically starts typing `GREEK SMALL LETTER` or `BOX DRAWINGS`.

This does not work, because `call-interactively` exits before `insert` is called:

```
(defun insert-box-drawing-char ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'insert-char)
  (insert "BOX DRAWING"))
```

How can I provide partial input to an interactive function?

Comment: Sounds like this might be an [X-Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/231821). Maybe try to explain why you think you want to do this - what you are really trying to do. Just a suggestion.

Comment: In this case, my use case of inserting specific characters is presented purely as example. An interesting X question in this case would be "How do I efficiently work with a subset of characters?". Another one would be "How can I filter the choices to an interactive function?". If those sound interesting, it would be great of you to add them to the community wiki. In this case I am curious about the technique of inserting text into the minibuffer, since I believe it may be a generally useful thing to know.

Comment: This will not help for a use case such as this one, where you do not have access to the call that initiates minibuffer reading (what's more, `insert-char` is coded in C), but it's maybe good to remind readers that both `completing-read` and `read-from-minibuffer` let you pass an `INITIAL-INPUT` argument, and you can position the cursor anywhere within that string, which is inserted in the minibuffer to start with. (Vanilla Emacs considers `INITIAL-INPUT` to be deprecated for `completing-read`, but that proscription can be ignored.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to invoke a command and have a given string automatically inserted at that command's interactive prompt.

You can do this using `minibuffer-setup-hook`, and there is a handy macro which takes care of adding and removing the desired function to this hook, while ensuring that it only runs when you wanted it to run:

```el
(minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    (lambda () (insert "BOX DRAWING"))
  (call-interactively 'insert-char))
```